# Impossible to resolve the name "ds:Signature" in a component element declaration

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, xml-signature

I'm struggling with the XML validation via XSD. I tried many and many variants , I tried to change the XSD with a more simple one , I tried to specify a ResourceResolver but nothing changed and honestly I don't have any idea.

The error i get

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 45; src-resolve: impossibile risolvere il nome "ds:Signature" in un componente element declaration.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)

The XSD i use is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
           schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
<xs:complexType name="headerType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="doorNumber" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Java Code

```
    String xml = "SOME XML ";
    Optional<List<SAXParseException>> optionalSAXParseExceptions = Optional.empty();
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(xsd);
    StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(inputStream);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(streamSource);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    final List<SAXParseException> exceptions = new LinkedList<SAXParseException>();
    validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

        public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXParseException {

            exceptions.add(exception);
        }


        public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXParseException {
            exceptions.add(exception);
        }


        public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXParseException {
            exceptions.add(exception);
        }
    });
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
```

Any suggestion will be helpful ! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , finally after hours and hours of research a colleague found this solution.

A class which implements LSInput like this

```
public class LSInputImpl implements LSInput {

private Reader characterStream;
private InputStream byteStream;
private String stringData;
private String systemId;
private String publicId;
private String baseURI;
private String encoding;
private boolean certifiedText;


public Reader getCharacterStream() {
    return characterStream;
}

public void setCharacterStream(Reader characterStream) {
    this.characterStream = characterStream;
}

public InputStream getByteStream() {
    return byteStream;
}

public void setByteStream(InputStream byteStream) {
    this.byteStream = byteStream;
}

public String getStringData() {
    return stringData;
}

public void setStringData(String stringData) {
    this.stringData = stringData;
}

public String getSystemId() {
    return systemId;
}

public void setSystemId(String systemId) {
    this.systemId = systemId;
}

public String getPublicId() {
    return publicId;
}

public void setPublicId(String publicId) {
    this.publicId = publicId;
}

public String getBaseURI() {
    return baseURI;
}

public void setBaseURI(String baseURI) {
    this.baseURI = baseURI;
}

public String getEncoding() {
    return encoding;
}

public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
    this.encoding = encoding;
}

@Override
public boolean getCertifiedText() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isCertifiedText() {
    return certifiedText;
}

public void setCertifiedText(boolean certifiedText) {
    this.certifiedText = certifiedText;
}
}
```

Another Class which implements LSResourceResolver like this

```
package test;

import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSInput;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CustomResolver implements LSResourceResolver {
    @Override
    public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {

        LSInputImpl input = new LSInputImpl();

        InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(systemId);

        input.setPublicId(publicId);
        input.setSystemId(systemId);
        input.setBaseURI(baseURI);
        input.setCharacterStream(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        return input;
    }
}
```

In the class which you use the SchemaFactory add this

```
factory.setResourceResolver(new CustomResolver());
```